# I just got an iPhone, but I only have Linux. How do I synchronise it?

Tags: ubuntu, iphone

Will [iTunes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITunes) run OK with [Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29) or what do I need to do? I use [Ubuntu 9.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29#Releases).

Answer (score 5):

From [what I've read](http://mediakey.dk/~cc/itunes-on-linux-ubuntu/), it's hit or miss as to whether Wine will run iTunes properly. I've had no problems running iTunes in a virtualized Windows environment using [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).

Answer (score -2):

+1 for @Jared, If you would like to know more about it, here the details 
[Virtual Box and Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/USB)

Comment: Couldn't this have gone into a comment to Jared's answer?